# Solve for down payment and closing costs, given savings, home price, and closing costs percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Assume I have 100K in savings and I'm purchasing a 500K home. How can I solve for the proportion of my 100K savings that goes towards down payment vs. closing costs, if closing costs are known to be 2% of my loan value? I can't figure out how to solve, since the loan value is dependent on the proportion of savings put towards closing costs, and closing costs are dependent on the loan value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean to spend all 100K when buying the home, let $d$ be the amount of your down payment and $c$ the amount of your closing costs. Then your conditions amount to saying that
\begin{gather*}
d+c = 100000\\
c = 0.02(500000-d)
\end{gather*}
since $500000-d$ is your loan value.

Can you take it from there?